# JQuery response seem return nothing

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi I was an issues that Seem post didn't return any response to Jquery, could someone point out my mistake?
My Html

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitle</title>

    <script src="./script/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./script/jquery.masonry.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./script/missingkids.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
        <div>Call to JS and return <br />
            <div id="retnTxt">Return Info</div>
            <input type="button" id="btnCallJs" onclick="BtnCal()" value="CallJS" />
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

my JS missingkids

```
var rtnObj = null;
var ds_handler = "ds_handle.aspx";
function BtnCal()
{
    //alert("asdf");
    $.post(ds_handler,
        {"Action":"MainAct", "SubAction":"SubAct"},
             function(response)
             {
                alert(response); //no alert running here??
                rtnObj = response.Data

                $("#retnTxt").html(rtnObj);
             }, "json"); 

}
```

my handle aspx.cs

```
public partial class MissingKids_handle : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            if (Request.Form["Action"] == "MainAct")
            {
                if (Request.Form["SubAction"] == "SubAct")
                {

                    string ans = "Hello";
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Write(ans);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just want to return the value to Return Info but, seem doesn't work. Can someone point out my miss take?

Thanks

Comment: Do take pcap of your server response check whether server is responding the response or not

Comment: Did you check if your handler ever get the request? (as in debugging - check for exceptions aswell). +1 for including all relevant code.

Comment: I had check the handler, its has

Answer (score 0):

You are probably receiving an error in the response.  The function you are using with the `$.post()` only responds for success.

Try adding functions for `.error()` and `.complete()` as well:

```
$.post(...)
.error(function(){...})
.complete(function(){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is `Hello` which isn't json so there is an error when jQuery attempts to parse it therefore the success callback never fires. To avoid the error json encode your response.

Comment: @user994985 try `string ans = "\"Hello\"";`

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have only forgotten a semicolon in the following line:

```
rtnObj = response.Data
```

Greetings,

Comment: Thanks for point out the semicolon. However, it still no return. The alert after function(response) did not prompt. However, handler, if had check it has output while i change request.from to request.querystring and using URL to run the handler. Why??

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer (to Musa's) and based **only** on your code above:

Your "handler" is returning a `string`, not `JSON`:

1. change the last parameter of `$.post` to `text` (because that is what your `ds_handle.aspx` is returning). This should make your `alert` work.
2. However, `rtnObj` will be `undefined` because your return data `response` is not JSON (there is no `response.Data`, the returned value is a `string: Hello`. So based **only** on your code above, which returns a string, `$("#retnTxt").html(response);`